Three-fence construction in mathml not working in browsers?

In this growing braket construction:
<math displaystyle="true">
    <mi>y</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mrow>
       <mo>⟨</mo>
       <mrow>
         <mfrac><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi></mfrac>
       </mrow>
       <mo>|</mo>
       <mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow>
       <mo>⟩</mo>
    </mrow>
</math>

the middle fence (vertical bar) doesn't grow in either Firefox or Chrome. Is it a bug according to the MathML specs?
See also related TeX question that seems to have an answer using braket* LaTeX macro:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex

Oops! If we add stretchy="true" attribute to the middle fence (vertical-bar) it works! So what's preventing it from adding it by default!

If we add any other fence character in the middle fence it automatically triggers stretchy="true" property!
